# EXCEPTION: Attempt to detect changes on a dehydrated detector

Tags: angular

Following is my simple custom directive which fetches a jsonp asset and displays it.

```
 @Directive({ selector: 'cms', viewInjector: [httpInjectables],
      properties:['assets'],
      lifecycle:[LifecycleEvent.onDestroy]
      })
    // We inherit from the default RouterOutlet
    export class cms {
      $elemRef: any;
      subscription:any;
      jsonpRequest:any;
      constructor(ngEl: ElementRef, jsonp:Jsonp ) {
        this.$elemRef = $(ngEl.nativeElement);      
        this.jsonpRequest= jsonp.get("https://www.host.com?id=assetId&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK").toRx();
        this.jsonpRequest.subscribe(function(data){
            $(ngEl.nativeElement).html(data._body.assetID);
          });
      }
      onDestroy(){
        this.jsonpRequest.dispose();
      }
    }
```

At some point when the request is being processed I destroy the bootstrapped app using *appRef.dispose()*.
I get following exception on the request completion:

```
EXCEPTION: Attempt to detect changes on a dehydrated detector.
```

It seems change detection is getting triggered on JSONP callback for the disposed app. And since app is not there (or dehydrated) exception is thrown (I guess).

I used *detach function of change Detector Ref* for the app before calling dispose hoping change detection wont be triggered for this app and for its child directive (my directive here).
But I guess I am terribly wrong somewhere.

Can some explain how to go about this problem?

**TL;DR:
If app is disposed and a pending callback is executed, what can I do to avoid DehydratedException?**

**EDIT**
I have temporarily fix the issue by force detaching the component and its host container before disposing the component itself. Example:

```
@Inject(ChangeDetectorRef)
class baseComponent{
    cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
    constructor(cd:ChangeDetectorRef){
        this.cd=cd;
    }

    forceDetach(){
      this.cd._cd.parent.mode=DETACHED;
      this.cd.detach();
    }
}
```

and doing:

```
appRef.hostComponent.forceDetach();
appRef.dispose();
```

I know its a hack. Waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Hard to say... Why would you destroy the app? I think the error makes sense. If you really need to dispose (un-load) the app you should do it when the jsonp request ends or detect somehow when the app was disposed and avoid the jsonp callback.

Comment: Consider a large scale application where modules are dynamically loaded and bootstrapped based on route or hash params.
So if I hit #Services/Todo1 Todo1 app will be loaded and bootstraped. If i move on to #Services/Todo2 I will have to unload the Todo1 app immediately and load and bootstrap the Todo2 app. 
If Some XHR requests of Todo1 are pending I should ideally abort them to avoid any memory leak. JSONP cannot be cancelled though so I have to make sure if callback is executed no weird things happen because user has already moved on...

Comment: Well avoiding the callback will do.. some approach will be good... Currently I am disposing the observable...but CD is still triggered causing the exception..

Comment: Interesting. Since the user can move from one route to another in any moment it wouldn't be a safe approach to avoid the callback. I think it would be safe to avoid the app being disposed depending on if the jsonp callback finished or not. Something like : `Starts the callback, hold a value in some service (maybe?) indicating that the it's running so we don't dispose the app. When the callback ends change that value to allow the app being disposed`.

Comment: To me, it sounds like angular is doing this for you already. This error means that the object no longer exists in the memory and this means that you may not need to do anything to destroy it.