# Angular exception : attempt to use a dehydrated detector

Tags: angular

After looking at several topics discussing this error, I can't find any reason for my code to produce `EXCEPTION: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: PortsInputComponent_1 -> valueChange`. I don't think the stacktrace is usefull, since it is only angular code, and not mine.

I've looked at those posts : [Angular2 EXCEPTION: Attempt to detect changes on a dehydrated detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952068/angular2-exception-attempt-to-detect-changes-on-a-dehydrated-detector), [EXCEPTION: Attempt to detect changes on a dehydrated detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841202/exception-attempt-to-detect-changes-on-a-dehydrated-detector), [What is a dehydrated detector and how am I using one here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515254/what-is-a-dehydrated-detector-and-how-am-i-using-one-here), and at this github issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786.

They all seem to be using some asynchronous operations, which I'm not, and none of those solutions fit my project. Please don't close it as duplicate.

Basically what I'm trying to do is a special input for multiple ports. I want to always have a blank input, so the user don't have to press a button in order to add a new one. I don't want to have more than one blank input though, so I need to remove them when the user deletes the last character. The demo below does this perfectly.

Here is the code inside the plunker :

```
import { Component, Input }             from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-ports-input',
  template:`
<div layout-gt-sm="row" layout-wrap>

  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm
      *ngFor="#port of values() ; #i = index ;">
    <label>Port</label>
    <input md-input class="ports-input" type="text" size="6"
        [value]="port.title" (input)="changeValueAtIndex(i, $event)" />
  </md-input-container>
</div>
`
})

export class PortsInputComponent {
  // More complex model that contains an array of string values
  @Input() attribute: {value : string[]}
  strings = []

  changeValueAtIndex(index, event) {
    // Case where we changed the value of the latest port : we add a new input
    if (!this.attribute.value[index]) {
      this.strings.push({ title: '' })
    }

    this.attribute.value[index] = event.target.value

    if (event.target.value.length === 0) {
      this.attribute.value.splice(index, 1)
      this.strings = [] // Should reload the array, but also causes the issue below
    }
  }

  // Use this function that returns an array of objects instead of an array of string.
  // Using directly attribute.value (array of string) cause this error:
  // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786
  //
  // Returning directly this.attribute.value.map((value) => { return {title: value} })
  // causes an infinite loop of error... for some reason
  // So use an intermediate variable instead
  values() {
    if (!this.strings.length) {
      let values: string[] = this.attribute.value
      this.strings = values.map((value) => { return {title: value} })
      this.strings.push({ title: '' })
    }
    return this.strings
    // return this.attribute.value.map((value) => { return {title: value} })
  }
}
```

Does anyone understands why this error is thrown in my case ?

I wanted to reproduce this error in [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WabcfNknhQ4LnhgxAKmH), but unfortunately it doesn't cause any exception, the only difference I see between my app and the plunker is the `attribute` variable. In my app it is a model and not a JSON object, could it change something ?

Comment: The Plunker example runs with `beta.8` therefore it should be reproducible. AFAIR it's related to components firing an event after or while being removed.

Comment: Indeed, I looked at the README.md file which states beta 0 even if it loads beta 8 in the index.
That's also what I understood from the github issue, but can't figure out why it happens in my case.

Comment: The readme is just outdated.

Comment: Is there a way to find which part of my code cause this error ?

Comment: I assume it's related to event binding with dynamically generated inputs in `src/ports-input.component.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delaying this code a bit might be able to work around (not tested because I can't reproduce)

```
  changeValueAtIndex(index, event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Case where we changed the value of the latest port : we add a new input
      if (!this.attribute.value[index]) {
        this.strings.push({ title: '' })
      }

      this.attribute.value[index] = event.target.value

      if (event.target.value.length === 0) {
        this.attribute.value.splice(index, 1)
        this.strings = [] // Should reload the array, but also causes the issue below
      }
    },0});
  }
```

Comment: A setTimeOut of 1ms (0 did not work) around the line `this.strings = []` removed the error, thank you. Though could you explain why delaying this code of 1ms would prevent an event to be fired from a removed component ?

Comment: There are some things that nudge change while Angular is still processing the previous change. `setTimeout` just changes the order in which things are processed. Angular can complete it's stuff and this code is executed only afterwards when Angular is again in a stable state. When the issue is fixed in Angular it should take care internally that things aren't executed out of the expected order.